# Problems with Mat structure and memcpy

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to copy a `Mat` structure from OpenCV into another `Mat` using `memcpy` (I'm using OpenCV 2.4.3 in Windows)

Basically the code is:

```
Mat NewFrame,OldFrame;
OldFrame=imread(image,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
memcpy(&NewFrame,&OldImage,sizeof(Mat));
```

The problem is that the NewFrame and OldFrame aren't the same. The address of `NewFrame.step.buf` has changed after this memcpy (???)

Before the memcpy, the addresses of `step` field from OldFrame were:

```
 OldFrame.step.p=0x0032f338
 OldFrame.step.buf=0x0032f338
```

After the memcpy,  the addresses of `step` field from NewFrame are:

```
 NewFrame.step.p=0x0032f338
 NewFrame.step.buf=0x0032f2f8 // it should be 0x0032f338
```

I don't understand why the addresses have changed and how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Any reason not to use `cv::Mat::clone`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes. This code comes from a larger project, where I put some `Mat` structures inside a template vector, which grows dynamically , and when it grows it's doing a `memcpy` and `delete` (just like realloc).

Answer (score 3):

"Any reason not to use cv::Mat::clone? – juanchopanza 48 mins ago"

PLEASE, believe that guy, god kills kittens, if you use memcpy on cv::Mat's this way!

also, they are refcounted, so they can handle being put into a std::vector pretty nice on their own, no need to delete them. realloc is a C thing, this is C++!

so, you can do a 'shallow' copy, Mat a,b; b=a; ( now a and b point to the same memory, refcount got increased.)
or a deep copy, Mat a,b, b = a.clone(); ( now both got their own copy of the pixels )

using plain memcpy there is similar to the shallow copy, it just does not handle the refcounts properly, so both src and dst of your memcpied Mat will have dangling pointers sooner or later.

Comment: Sorry man, but you didn't respond to my question. I understand the benefits of clone, but I can't use clone, because this comes from a template vector. I asked why the `buf` from `step` member has changed during a `memcpy`.

Comment: i don't know, why your step member changed there. made a test and it did not happen here(but shure it crached with heap corruption). i'm just trying to get you away from memcpy, as it corrupts the refcounts of both src and dst. explain, why did you want memcpy at all  ?